# Testing with jasmine-node : understanding error

Tags: javascript, jasmine-node

I'm trying to learn javascript by doing some of the exercises over on [exercism.io](http://exercism.io/) (which provides pre-written tests that we need to make pass). It was going okay for a while but with this latest exercise I can't seem to figure out how the tests work.

The aim of the exercise is to write a programme that will count the number of times a given string appears within another string. This is how the test file looks:

```
var words = require('./word-count');

describe("words()", function() {
  it("counts one word", function() {
    var expectedCounts = { word: 1 };
    expect(words("word")).toEqual(expectedCounts);
  });

  // more skipped tests  

});
```

The first thing I did was create the `word-count.js` file but I don't know how code in that file needs to be formatted/setup to be read by the spec file. After glancing through [this tutorial](http://blog.codeship.com/jasmine-node-js-application-testing-tutorial/) I setup `word-count.js` like so:

```
exports = function(str){}
```

However this (and everything else I've tried) gives me the error

```
  1) words() counts one word
   Message:
     TypeError: object is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: object is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/sheeka/exercism/javascript/word-count/word-count_test.spec.js:6:12)
```

I don't understand this error, or what it's looking for. I also don't understand how the tests are working since it doesn't look to me like the spec file is calling on any functions or variables from `word-count.js`

Any help understanding this or pointing me in the direction of resources I could use to figure this out would be much appreciated. I did try running a google search but everything I've found looks much too advanced for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `exports = function(str){}` don't make your function public. please try `module.exports = function(str){}`.
Alternatively you can assign function as exports prop `exports.fc = function() {...};`

By default `exports` is an empty object that points to `module.exports`. When you override `exports`, module.exports stays unchanged.

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thank you! I've been trying for ages to figure this out. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me :)